# How Do I Return the Index of type T in a Collection based on some criteria?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin has some pretty cool functions for collections. However, I have come across a problem in which the solution is not apparent to me.

I have a List of Objects. Those Objects have an ID field which coincides with a SQLite database. SQL operations are performed on the database, and a new list is generated. **How can the index of an item from the new list be found based on the "ID" field (or any other field for that matter)?**

the Collection.find{} function return the object, but not the index.

Comment: [`indexOfFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html`)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Your link is broken

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html

Comment: That is it @LouisWasserman . Could you post an answer with some verbage as well as post a link, and I will mark your answer as correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`indexOfFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html) can find the index of the first element of a collection that satisfies a specified predicate.

Answer (score -1):

We have a DB SQlite that a call is made to to retrieve parentList We can obtain the items in the ArrayList with this type of code

```
    fun onDoIt(view: View){

    initDB()


    for (t in 0..X-1) {
        var N:String = parentList[t].dept
        // NOTE two syntax here [t] and get(t)
        if(t == 1){
            var B:String = parentList[0].idD.toString()
            println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ====== "+B)
        }
        var I:String = parentList.get(t).idD.toString()
        println("################### id "+I+" for "+N)
    }

}

private fun initDB() {
    parentList = db.querySPDept()
    if (parentList.isEmpty()) {
        title = "No Records in DB"
    } else {
        X = parentList.size
        println("**************************************** SIZE " + X)
        title = "SP View Activity"
    }
}
```